# Returning an rvalue reference from a nonlocal

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, rvalue-reference

I have a class that is queried for an internal state object:

```
class State {...}; //Has a copy and move constructor
class Processor
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<State> state;

public:
    void process(...)
    {
        State newState;
        ... //create this new state
        state.reset(new State(newState));
    }

    State getState()
    {
        return std::move(*state.release());
    }
};
```

Is this an appropriate use of `std::move`? I can guarantee that `getState` will only be called once per call to `process`, but because of the design of this particular system I can't just return `newState` from `process`. Many of the other answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere said that it's better to just return the object, because the compiler will move it or RVO it if it can anyway, but those were all in the case that the returned object was local to the function.

I don't necessarily need the state object to be behind a unique_ptr, but that seemed like the easiest way to do manage the new state objects. My actual implementation has a pointer being transferred directly to the unique_ptr at the end.

Comment: Wouldn't shared_ptr be a better option?

Comment: I want to have the getState function just return the object. I don't want to expose the pointeryness of the implementation to the outside world.

Comment: You know this leaks, yes?

Comment: Why not expose a reference? Like a normal person? :)

Comment: So who's in charge of deleting the ex-managed ``State`` object after the call to ``getState()``?

Comment: I fixed the leak in my answer below. The answer is that the object should somehow end up on the stack after `getState()` returns, so it can be deleted normally when popped off the stack.

Comment: I'm curious as to the actual problem that this code is intended to solve?

Comment: I'm creating a library that provides functionality similar to Python's Generators, using POSIX context switching functions (http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/swapcontext.3.html). Every time the yield function is called, the value is stored in the state object, and the context switches back to the next() caller, where it is retrieved and returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the original demo code is buggy- the unique_ptr never frees the pointer. The answer involves moving *onto* the local function space and then returning normally.

```
class State {...}; //Has a copy and move constructor
class Processor
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<State> state;

public:
    void process(...)
    {
        State* newState;
        ... //newState is allocated on the heap somehow
        state.reset(newState);
    }

    State getState()
    {
        State _state(std::move(*state));
        //Optionally: state.reset();
        return _state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just returning state

```
struct state {};
class processor {
public:
  void process() {
    state_ = State();
  }

  state get_state() {
    return std::move(state_);
  }

private:
  state state_;
};
```

This will default-construct state_ when a processor is constructed but
you can prevent that with an `optional` wrapper. You still have to
guarantee that `get_state` is only called after `process`, which
outright sucks.

Comment: The guarantee about `get_state()` and `process(...)` is awful when looking at just this example code, but in the actual project I'm working on it makes sense. I'm wrapping the state in a unique_ptr because the `process(...)` function may set it to `nullptr` if there is no result state.

Comment: @Lucretiel And what would `get_state` possibly return in such a case? Obviously, you don't need a pointer, but `boost::optional` (or something similar) and then return a reference to said optional in `get_state`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return the `state` whose type is `std::unique_ptr<State>`, it would be perfectly moved with `std::move(state)`. In this case you are free from copying the whole `state` object when it's returned by value. And the `state` object would be automaticaly destroyed if it's not captured by the caller. It's quite efficient approach for complex heap-allocated objects. But be careful, by moving `state` you are clearing the state of the `Processor` object. So, the `getState` isn't a best name in this case, it should be like `fetchState` or `popState`.