# returning move only types from free function vs member function

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value

Let me brief the actual scenario first :

I have created a class template called `error<T>` which holds the type T and error related variables.
The constructor is like so

```
error(T&&,..other_params...)
```

and there is a utility function that generates this which is defined as so

```
template<typename T>
make_error(T&& val_T,..other_params..)
{return error<T>(std::forward<T&&>(val_t),..other_params..);}
```

i use this type as return type instead of just the type T. basically it just wraps the type with error info.

it has a getter which gets the value of the type contained:

```
T get()
{ return val_T_int;}
```

where `val_T_int` is initalized with the `val_t` above.
When i use a move only type this `get` gives an error saying `delete copy constructor being used`.

Q1. why does it say this?why wont it move construct the value?i.e i have to explicitly use std::move() on the return value.

Q2. if Q1 is not possible then how would i enable such a feature where the user, instead of returning a type would return this error .i could not use `boost::optional` because it needs the type to be `copy constructible`?

my compiler : minGW GCC 4.8.2 on windows 7.

for example :

```
class B //a move only type
{
    B( const B& )=delete;
    B& operator=( const B& ) = delete;
public:
    B( B&& )
    {
        std::cout << "B&&\n";
    }

    B& operator=( B&& )
    {
        std::cout << "B=\n";
            return *this; 
    }
    B(){ std::cout << "B()\n"; }
};

struct error  //the other parts are stripped of for simplicity.
{
    B get()
    {
        return std::move(b);
    }
private :
    B b{};// B is a move only type.
};

error er{};
er.get(); //error:use of deleted function B(const B&)!.
```

what am i not understanding here?. 
Thanks for reading.

P.S [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614903/returning-an-rvalue-reference-from-a-nonlocal) is close but i dont understand the reason for the local variable.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055266/return-a-move-only-object-from-member-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991874/why-is-this-code-trying-to-call-the-copy-constructor?answertab=votes#tab-top) also dint help

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code and it works well (http://ideone.com/EonjFP). May be you are doing `auto x = er.get();` and that calls for the copy-ctor.

Comment: @zahir no i dont use auto in the situation that i'm getting the error. But after you pointed out i moved i.e std::move(er.get()) and it works since the contained element is move-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following code. If the `get` method would move the *string* out of the member variable, what should be the value of `t`?

```
error e = make_error(std::string{"foobar"});
std::string s = e.get();
std::string t = e.get();
```

You can return a reference to the member variable. It might look as follows:

```
const T& get() const { return val_T_int; }
```

The problem with that solution is, that you can't use it with non-copyable types the following way:

```
std::unique_ptr<...> result = make_error(...).get();
```

However, you can use *rvalue-references for this* to solve this problem. If you declare `get` in the following way, the function can only be used on *temporaries* (and explicitly *moved* objects). So it's fine to move the member variable out of the object.

```
T get() && { return std::move(val_T_int); }
```

Comment: yes the scenario you pointed out was there in my mind. i planned to use a is_valid flag and then document it. i think i'l try the ref-qualifier way and check it out. basically i could overload on the ref_qualifier type right?

Comment: Yes, you can overload it. Just add a function `T& get() & { ... }`.

Comment: i tested your solution and came to the conclusion that since the contained type was a move-only the structure itself becomes move-only and thus if i have to get the type i had to make the data_structure an xvalue and then get(). do you agree with this?. i will implement your method and go from there. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `get()` wants to return a copy, so it need the copy-ctor. If you'd move the internal value `val_T_int` to the returned value, you'd invalidate `val_T_int`. You couldn't access its value afterwards which is probably not what you want.

One solution that comes to mind: Don't return a value, just allow (const) access:

```
const T& get() const
{
    return val_T_int;
}
```

If you also want/need non-const access, add a second overload:

```
T& get()
{
    return val_T_int;
}
```

which allows users of your class to even modify `val_T_int`, e.g. `er.get() = 42;`.

Comment: ah yes i also had in mind that val_t_int would be invalidated.  but i want the type to be mutable. so since the user knows the type he passed its ok for him to const_cast this right? for the edit : i dont want to use the value afterwards either. i wanted to keep is_valid flag to indicate if get() is possible or not.